# How can I view the Azure App Service log files?

Tags: asp.net, logging, azure-appservice

The default API example in Visual Studio 2019 instantiates an `ILogger<T>`. If I invoke it via `_logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "hello")` how can I view the log file? This question assumes use of Azure App Service.

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can stream logs live in Cloud Shell, use the following command:

   az webapp log tail --name appname --resource-group myResourceGroup
2. Or you can navigate to your app and select Log stream.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am sharing the Azure portal steps in Azure App Service and also the code required for it.

1. First of all enable logging via App Service Logs Options
   [image]
2. Then check out the live log via 'Log Stream' Option
   [image]
3. Also sharing my code change for .netcore 3.1

   using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog;

   ```
    namespace MPRC.Common.SAMPLE
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }

            public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                    {
                        logging.ClearProviders();
                        logging.AddConfiguration(..sample...);                    
                        logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings()
                        {
                        //...........
                        });
                        logging.AddConsole();
                        logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
                    })
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    });
   ```
4. Just take a note of logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(); in above code

Comment: unfortunately outdated. the user interface has changed and does not contain half the options listed then

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the methods from namespace System.Diagnostics.Trace to register info about diagnostic

`eg: System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("If you're seeing this, something bad happened");`

By Default, .NET use this provider for logs:

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices.`